# Is it possible to do water detection with a single electrode?

Tags: sensor, capacitance, detection, water

I need to detect the presence of water, but there is a catch. I can only have one single electrode contacting/submerged in water. It is in a mini-tank made of plastic (for a handheld device) so I cannot even have a ground probe with the tank.

Could I somehow measure the change in capacitance of the electrode in water vs air? Is this possible without a ground reference point?

I imagine some similar setup as this - https://docs.arduino.cc/tutorials/generic/capacitance-meter/

Would this work without a ground reference to the water? Is there some other method that I can use with a single-electrode?

[image]

Comment: The container must be conductive and grounded.

Comment: Is the electrode imposed? If not, you can easily have a single electrode in a "mechanical" sens (ie a single stick) but with 2 distinct electrodes from an electric poitn of view. A very simple solution would be a small strip cut out of a stripline prototyping PCB where you keep just 2 parallel copper lines. Of course, if it is for long term use, you might want some material less subject to corrosion than copper

Comment: Is this plastic bottle in all possible circumstances (on a wooden shelf, in someone's hand, etc.) none of which is controlled in any way and must it also be a single electrode? And if a single electrode, what precisely must the probe material be, if known? Must it be food-grade 304 steel? Or?

Comment: Is the "single electrode" constraint coming from the fact it is supposed to be connected to a single BBB pin? If so, it can be worked around.

Comment: What is the size of the tank and how thick is the plastic?

Comment: I have a water tank level sensor on my boat that uses two vertical copper foil strips attached to the outside of the plastic tank - nothing inside the tank.  There is a small module connected to the strips, and a three-wire connection (power, ground and signal) to the display.  I don't know what principle the system uses, but this information might guide you to a solution...

Comment: @PeterBennett does it look something like this? https://defender.com/en_us/scad-technologies-external-tape-on-tank-sensor-10022

Comment: @hacktastical: yes, but New Providence Marine has it for $36.

Comment: Why not use a US sensor (only one)? It could be outside the tank. https://www.amazon.com.be/-/en/Waterproof-Ultrasonic-Transducer-measuring-obstacles/dp/B0BSH74KKZ/ref=asc_df_B0BSH74KKZ/?tag=begogshpadde-21&linkCode=df0&hvadid=633217882695&hvpos=&hvnetw=g&hvrand=10558956058395213210&hvpone=&hvptwo=&hvqmt=&hvdev=c&hvdvcmdl=&hvlocint=&hvlocphy=1001150&hvtargid=pla-2089067076230&psc=1&mcid=be177d5aec4830108f33f3dbf09faa43&language=en_GB

Comment: If the tank is made of plastic and handheld, it seems like the capacitance will change significantly even when the user merely changes the way they're holding the device.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

If all you need is to detect the presence of liquid, you could use an optical method instead. Then you don't need any electrical connecton at all to the liquid or the  tank.

The principle is very simple: an LED - phototransistor pair is arranged with a prism. When there is no liquid, the prism reflects; when liquid is present, the prism refracts and no light gets back to the phototransistor.

Here's an illustration:

[image]

From here: https://www.electroschematics.com/optical-liquid-level-sensor/

These sensors are not expensive. They're popular in the aquarium trade for example. Use several of them to indicate rough levels (e.g., 1/4 half 3/4 etc.)

Capacitive liquid level sensors measure the charge / discharge on a pair of electrodes, with the capacitance being proportional to how much of the electrodes are covered by (or in proximity to) the liquid. These don't require contact with the fluid itself. More about this here: https://www.analog.com/en/resources/analog-dialogue/articles/liquid-level-sensing-using-cdcs.html

And it appears that an external tape-on capacitive liquid sensor is a common product in the boating industry (thx to Peter Bennett for the tip). These use two electrodes on the outside of the tank so it doesn't need a 'ground' per se. Seems like this approach would work for you.
More info: https://tankedge.com/downloads/How_our_exterior_Moda_tank_sensors_work.pdf

Answer (score 3):

#### research, research, research

There are articles on the topic of charge storage in water in the research literature. I'm not going to list any of them here because I'd have to first review them for application and (1) I'm not even sure exactly what your application is; and, (2) It would be a lot of work that you should be doing, not me. But you should make some attempts here to find and evaluate the possibilities.

My own mental models about the idea are probably deficient as my chemistry and related physics backgrounds are minimal. But I can make some general guesses about using a single electrode where it must be food-grade 304 steel (or maybe 316.)

My first choice to gain a leg up on understanding these things better (and this is left for you, not me) would be the 1973 edition of *"The Chemistry of Electrode Processes"* by Ilana Fried. Any attempt to change or alter the voltage on the probe may slightly alter the number of nearby OH- or H+ ions in proximity to the surface of the probe in water. (Technically, this is only true if there were a 2nd probe. But my ignorance allows the idea that the ambient environment surrounding the water can allow very small variations.) So with AC applied there may be some slight back-and-forth of charge motion. But I wouldn't expect to see a lot.

Bottom line is that you should perform your own research on the topic. You know your circumstances *better than anyone else*. You can interpret what you read and consider it in the context of your situation *better than anyone else*. You can consider changing/modifying/altering your initial ideas based on what you gain from this study *better than anyone else*.

So this is **job #1** for you, right now. Do your research. Then come back here, inform us, and ask a better question based upon your new state of mind, thoughts, and research materials.

#### experimental suggestion

The above point made, I do have a single thought about an experiment that may help make a useful observation. However, like any experiment into the unknown, I cannot tell you that it will yield ***useful*** results. You may only find out that the idea produces nothing of use and only tells you that my idea is really just a dead-end. Even then, though, at least it would close off one avenue from further study and it would also help you better interpret the above research that you still need to do.

So, if you are game, get out a logbook and perform this experiment.

The idea here is to create a very fast edge and see what happens with a probe in water vs the same probe out of water. The following circuit can produce a very very fast edge:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f7HzLp.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Make sure to use the 74AS14 here. It's a shockingly fast Schmitt trigger and will create very sharp edges.

Also, in construction, make absolutely sure to provide a bypass capacitor soldered as close as possible to the 74AS14 IC's power pins. That's important. The same goes for the resistors. These should be kept with very short leads to the actual probe itself. The goal here is to take as good of care as possible in the construction to avoid as much as possible in uncontrolled and/or unknown effects so that you can focus on whether or not anything useful is to be seen from this.

You can either use the first stage to create the oscillator or you can drive it with a 555 of some kind or you can drive it with an MCU board. That's your call.

A question is what to do with your ground. (Obvious question without two probes.) I may consider drawing out several different ideas in my logbook to try. Could just be a nearby wand adjacent to the water. Could be just a plate as the bottle top. Could be other things. But I'd write them down as a list of ideas I'd like to try in the logbook before starting out, listing them in my preferred order.

The next problem is to see if you can "see anything here." I'd recommend having a very good oscilloscope to monitor the response at the tip here.

#### expect negative results

I frankly don't think you will get good results because there's no managed ground reference to consider and I expect things to quickly find an equilibrium state that makes observation of something useful `rather unlikely`. (There aren't two probes here so how will the output actually *do anything* in the water?)

But wherever the water sits, it is present in a world around. And it's all I can come up with as an experiment that doesn't cost a lot of time or money to build, assuming you have a scope already.

Answer (score 2):

You already have a ground reference. It's the circuit, and its power supply, and you.

The problem is getting a sufficiently repeatable ground for the measurement such that the changes in capacitance are meaningful, ie dependent on the test electrode <-> water distance much more than the water <-> grounded things distance.

It may be good enough that hold the tank with your hand, and earth yourself to the circuit's power supply.

If you can put the plastic tank into a metal container and connect that to the circuit ground, that would be even better.

Answer (score 0):

You will nee a ground reference.

Put some copper tape on the outside of the plastic tank near the bottom and solder that to your circuit ground. The copper table will capacitively couple to the water in the tank.

The other electrode could be another copper tape if you want.